# tmux: rotate panes vertically or horizontally

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to get tmux to do the equivalent of Vim's window rotation (ctrl-w r and ctrl-R), where it rotates only in one direction? Tmux's normal window swap command ( ctrl-o) just rotates all panes around in a kind of circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: try  Ctrl+F3 and Ctrl+F4 t swap upper or lower panes. You can also iterate to reach other configurations.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the "swap-pane" command, e.g. swap-pane -U. Mine had a binding from { and }.

Comment: Keyboard shortcut didn't work, but @mahemoff's comment did.

Comment: I found `CTL-B {` and `CTL-B }` will rotate panes, that may produce the effect being looked for. Obviously change `CTL-B` for whatever leader / prefix you are using.